# How do you call groups formed as direct sums of cyclic groups?

Tags: homology-cohomology, abelian-groups

What do you call groups of the form $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}d_1\oplus\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}d_2\oplus\cdots$
These kind of groups usualy appear as homology groups.
Is it just a classification of abelian groups?

Comment: Countably generated ablian group, maybe? I may be missing some subtleties here which will surely be pointed out to me.

Comment: I'm curious, where do these groups appear as the homology groups of some space?

Comment: Just a guess but the nature of the groups you described seem to be related to statement of the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, in which every finitely generated abelian group is classified in a similar nature : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Primary_decomposition